# ErrorException: Trying to get property 'max_score' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I have this code:

Controller

```
$data = AppraisalGoalType::create([
    'name'                      => $request->name,
    'parent_id'                 => $request->parent_id,
    'max_score'                 => $request->max_score,
    'company_id'                => Auth::user()->company_id,
]);

$data1 = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
    ->select('max_score')
    ->where('id', $request->parent_id)
    ->whereNull('parent_id')
    ->first();

if (!empty($request->max_score)) {
    $data->update(['max_score1' => $data1->max_score]);
} else {
    $data->update(['max_score1' => 0]);
}
```

View

```xml
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Max. Score:</label>
    <input type="number" name="max_score" class="form-control" value="{{ old('max_score') }}" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter maximum weight here: 15, 50, 75 etc" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

When I tried to insert into the database, I got this error:

> ```
> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'max_score' of non-object
> ```

I `dd($data);` and got:

```
#original: array:12 [▼
    "name" => "dxxddxdx"
    "parent_id" => null
    "max_score" => "56"
    "company_id" =>
```

and `dd($data1);` gives `null` which is true. I already have a conditional statement.

I see that it has  `"max_score" => "56"`

Why the error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: $data1->max_score,  if $data1 is null so that throws the error

Comment: Side note: Laravel 5.x is not supported anymore. Please consider upgrading to version 6.x, 7.x or 8.x. See [Laravel Versions](https://laravelversions.com/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

your select statement not correct , you trying to select first row where id =  parent_id and the parent_id = null so this is always return null because id column in auto increment and the parent id is number you get it from request . and in your case parent id equal null , you compare value that auto increment with null value that return null . that mean your condition not correct .
try to fix the select statement.

i dont know your business , but i think try to change this condition
->where('id', $request->parent_id)   to be
->where('parent_id', $request->parent_id)